# missing AdapterFactory Error during sub menu open

Tags: magento2, navigation, submenu, dicompilation, missing

I have facing this issue during sub menu navigation part open ,rest all website work fine. Current version :.4.2 ,apache 7.4 .
you can check online, the link is https://primalsupplements.co.nz/products/non-stim-burn/non-stim-burner.html

**ERROR IS**
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $adapters of Magento\Search\Model\AdapterFactory.

Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $adapters of Magento\Search\Model\AdapterFactory.

#1 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:170]
#5 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:276]
#6 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:239]
#7 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34]
#8 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59]
#9 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#10 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:170]
#11 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:276]
#12 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:239]
#13 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34]
#14 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59]
#15 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]

Answer (score 0):

`sudo service elasticsearch restart` if this running correctly,
then check your module `php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Elasticsearch6 Magento_Elasticsearch Magento_Elasticsearch7`

this error is related to ElasticSearch as magento 2.4 need elastic search.

Comment: Thanks the answer,but I have used share hosting, the hosting  company not provide elastic module for this plan,so provide me other alternatives I shall be very thankful.

Comment: If magento version 2.4 then elasticsearch is required bro.. you must disabled all elasticsearch related module that's why facing error. try to fix it otherwise you have to go with VPN or Dedicated server